# pandas matplotlib barh bars print bottom to top but label print top to bottom

Tags: matplotlib, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has been sorted into ascending order by value. It looks like this.

```
    Name    Count
19  PAGEBGFX    1
18  CODE    1
17  .orpc   2
16  .sdata  3
15  PAGE    4
14  PAGELK  4
13  .data1  4
12  data    6
11  .tls    6
10  text    6
9   .ndata  8
8   minATL  13
7   .imrsiv 41
6   .rdata  209
5   .pdata  501
4   .idata  660
3   .reloc  896
2   .data   930
1   .rsrc   962
0   .text   998
```

When I plot this using a horizontal bar chart, the bars seem to fill from the bottom to the top. So the first line in my data frame is the bottom bar in my chart. Here is the plotting code.

```
ypos = np.arange(len(section_names_df)) + .1
plt.barh(ypos, section_names_df['Count'])
plt.yticks(ypos +.4, section_names_df['Name'])
plt.show()
```

[image: horizontal bar chart]

So the labels appear to have been populated from the top to the bottom of the data frame but the length of the bars was populated from the bottom to the top. Is that how it is supposed to be or did I do something wrong? Any pointers on how to make this easier?

**EDIT** I created an iPython notebook to demonstrate the problem with a full code reproducing the problem. http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/blackfist/dd0941f3ddbbc0f724a1

Comment: Further review seems to show the problem has to do with sorting the dataframe before plotting. If I don't sort it, then things look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling

```
section_names_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

before plotting. The problem is that dataframes are iterated in the order of the index, so it needs to be reset to match the sorted order.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Are you aware of a way to sort and reset_index in one command? It's kind of irritating.

Comment: @KevinThompson, I'm not aware of an elegant solution, but you could use something like df.index=numpy.argsort(df["column"]).

Comment: You might want to retitle the question to get more attention from pandas experts.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question, barh plots in the reverse order you would expect use this code to reverse your DataFrame before plotting:

```
df = df.iloc[::-1]
```